# How to use @types/lodash for the individual lodash.* libraries

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash, typescript-typings

In an effort to reduce the bundle size of my Angular project I am installing and importing individual lodash libraries. ie. `lodash.clonedeep` and other `lodash.*` but lose type definitions for these as the they do not work with the @types/lodash npm package.

I have tried to google around and find a way to alias the type definitions but haven't found anything for that.

```js
const cloneDeep = require('lodash.clonedeep');
```

```js
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash';
```

The first does not give me type information in my IDE where the second does as it uses @types/lodash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use the whole *@types/lodash* package for the individual lodash packages. Mostly, in all the cases you can get type definitions for the lodash individual
packages.

For *lodash.clonedeep*, you can get *@types/lodash.clonedeep* from npm  registry

Comment: Ok I swear I tried to `yarn add @types/lodash,<something>` in the past and it didn't. Clearly it wasn't cloneDeep because I just looked and it is there for sure. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Just installed them all except defaultTo, that one doesn't have an @types. Must have been the one I tried before.